# Get char array from byte array and then back to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I don't know why but when you do the next thing you will never get the same as the original byte array:

```
var b = new byte[] {252, 2, 56, 8, 9};
var g = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars(b);
var f = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(g);
```

If you will run this code you will see that b != f, Why?!
Is there any way to convert bytes to chars and then back to bytes and get the same as the original byte array?

Comment: Because `252` can't be be used as ASCII char(it is 7 bit). So converting between any arbitrary byte array and string can be lossy.

Comment: What do you want to do with the chars?

Comment: @L.B How I can fix it?

Comment: @AndrewMorton Does it matter?

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael use `Convert.ToBase64String` and `Convert.FromBase64String`

Comment: @L.B Is there any way to do this faster?

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael Yes convert the algorithm(or data) into smaller steps that can be run in parallel and use a super computer. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General-purpose_computing_on_graphics_processing_units

Comment: The fastest way to convert `byte[]` to something back to `byte[]` is clearly identity transformation :). If you can specify your exact requirement there could be some other way... (also Base64 is quite standard and easy to implement if you need to deal with huge arrays)

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael Yes, it matters because it might be that you do not need to go via chars.

Comment: @AndrewMorton It's good point, I will try without chars.

Comment: @ZilbermanRafael,if you want TABLE ASCII -II in encoding for value between 128 to 255, may be you can read my latest post. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**byte** value can be **0 to 255**.

When the byte value **> 127**, then result of

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetChars()
```

is always **'?'** which has value **63**

Therefore,

```
System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes()
```

result always get **63** (wrong value) for those have initial byte value **> 127**

---

If you need [TABLE ASCII -II](http://www.cdrummond.qc.ca/cegep/informat/professeurs/alain/files/ascii.htm) then you can do as following

```
        var b = new byte[] { 252, 2, 56, 8, 9 };
        //another encoding
        var e = Encoding.GetEncoding("437");
        //252 inside the mentioned table is ⁿ and now you have it
        var g = e.GetString(b);
        //now you can get the byte value 252
        var f = e.GetBytes(g);
```

Similar posts you can read

[How to convert the byte 255 to a signed char in C#](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/411ccdeb-63c3-4fda-8a6a-f86dd1352e4a/how-to-convert-the-byte-255-to-a-signed-char-in-c?forum=csharplanguage)

[How can I convert extended ascii to a System.String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/666385/how-can-i-convert-extended-ascii-to-a-system-string)

Answer (score 0):

Why not use chars?

```
var b = new byte[] {252, 2, 56, 8, 9};
var g = new char[b.Length];
var f = new byte[g.Length]; // can also be b.Length, doens't really matter
for (int i = 0; i < b.Length; i++)
{
   g[i] = Convert.ToChar(b[i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < f.Length; i++)
{
   f[i] = Convert.ToByte(g[i]);
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The only difference is first byte: 252. Because ascii char is 1-byte signed char and it's value range is -128 to 127. Actually your input is incorrect. signed char can't be 252.

Comment: I wasn't talking about actual ascii. I was talking about ascii in the code. I wrote purposely this way to be easy to understand. I know there is nothing called ascii unsigned char.

Comment: in c, refer answer @Adrian McCarthy, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13161199/ascii-table-negative-value
There is no such thing as a "negative ASCII" value. ASCII defines character and control codes for values from 0 to 127. therefore your answer has problem on **signed** char